# How would you explain what makes this part of the code start with monday when sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT ename, hiredate, INITCAP(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'day')) FROM emp
ORDER BY replace(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'd'), '1', '8');
```

We're showing the name, hiredate and day of hire by order of day starting with monday.
I tried reading the documentation and realized that d can range from 1 to 7.
What makes the code `replace(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'd'), '1', '8');` start with monday?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `to_char(<date>, 'd')` returns a string value for the date of the week that is `'1'` for Sunday up through `'7'` for Saturday.

The `replace()` changes the `'1'` to an `'8'`, so the values are `'2'` through `8`.  `'2'` is the value for Monday.

It is the smallest value so that is why Monday comes first.

I think is would be more natural to use the ISO definition of day-of-the-week which starts on Monday, which would be:

```
order by extract(isodow from <date>)
```

Comment: For the smol brains like me:


TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'd') returns 1 through 7 starting from Sunday to Saturday

Sunday - 1
Monday - 2
Tuesday - 3
Wednesday - 4
Thursday - 5
Friday - 6
Saturday - 7
 
Let's replace 1 for 8 using replace('1', '8')
 

Monday - 2
Tuesday - 3
Wednesday - 4
Thursday - 5
Friday - 6
Saturday - 7
Sunday - 8
 
 
Hence we start with monday.